# Google Firestore python library not working in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, google-cloud-firestore, serverless-framework

I am trying to use Google Cloud Firestore in my existing Serverless AWS Lambda application.

Here's what I have done.

I have added the library(google-cloud-firestore) in the requirement.txt
I have done the required setup and added creds json file.
I am using 'serverless-python-requirements' and docker deployment for the application deployment.

I can run everything fine on my local environment but when I deploy it on AWS lambda I get the following error.

```
module initialization error: The 'google-cloud-firestore' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I tried a lot. I have even tried forking the google cloud python repo and setting static values where `pkg_resources.get_distribution` is called. This seems to work but not the right solution.
Here's the link to the fork and edit. https://github.com/AmitChotaliya/google-cloud-python/commit/f23539f0905721f2b1b11d2439e351d438f541dd#diff-5e99793fe69a94f0f27267a2fba86306

Comment: Did you upload the package to Lambda? See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html  it doesn't look like just adding it to requirements.txt is enough

Comment: @jhomr, Yes I have done that. I am already using other custom pip packages like flask, simplejson, razorpay etc. They are working fine. Only the google library is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Here's what I was doing wrong.

I was using serverless framework and I am using 'serverless-python-requirements' and docker deployment for the application deployment.

My config was as below

```
custom:
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
    slim: true
```

The problem was the `slim: true`, it was excluding `.so` files. I removed it and it worked fine.